# Using endxldown function to copy and paste unlimited data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy and paste data from one workbook into another. This function works when the range is static, but I cannot get it to be dynamic. I know the endxldown function is for this, but how would I work it into my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim itemName As String

Dim itemPrice As Single

Dim myData As Workbook


Worksheets("Sheet1").Select

itemName = Range("A2")

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select

itemPrice = Range("B2")

Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Iraj.Masud\Desktop\testing\Master.xlsm")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select

RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

.Offset(RowCount, 0) = itemName

.Offset(RowCount, 1) = itemPrice

End With
myData.Save

End Sub
```

My edits are highlighted in the image below. When I ran the macro, I received an object variable or with block variable not set.

[Code with Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QtZY.png)

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).end(xlUp)
        .Offset(1, 0) = itemName
        .Offset(1, 1) = itemPrice
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Instead of your last with...end with block

Answer (score 0):

try this, (I cleaned up your code), see also the instruction that sets a value to rowcount

```
    Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

    Dim rowcount As Long
    Dim myData As Workbook

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    End With
    Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Iraj.Masud\Desktop\testing\Master.xlsm")
    With myData.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        rowcount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(rowcount, 1).Paste
    End With
    myData.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't copy anything beyond A1, B2

Comment: Lol yes I know. That is why I asked how to change the code to include a dynamic range.

Answer (score 0):

Use `End(xlUp)` from the bottom to capture the last row, this is better than using `xlDown` because the latter will capture the first empty row, not the last row.

Removing all the unnecessary `Select` stuff and using arrays, your code can be reduced to this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
  With Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Iraj.Masud\Desktop\testing\Master.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, 2).Value = _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B2").Value2
    .Parent.Close True
  End With
End Sub
```

Note that all references are explicit, there is no implicit reference to whichever workbook or worksheet is active. This usually results in safer code.

EDIT

If you want to copy all A:B data from the source, use this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
  Dim src as Range
  Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B999999").End(xlUp)
  With Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Iraj.Masud\Desktop\testing\Master.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) _
       .Resize(src.Rows.Count, src.Columns.Count).Value = src.Value2
    .Parent.Close True
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim itemName As String
Dim itemPrice As Single
Dim wbData As Workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim newData As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  '<~defines that we are working on sheet1
  itemName = .Range("A2")               '<~gets the itemname
  itemPrice = .Range("B2")              '<~gets the itemprice
End With

Set wbData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Iraj.Masud\Desktop\testing\Master.xlsm")  '<~opens then workbook
Set wsData = wbData.Worksheets("Sheet1")                                        '<~sets the worksheet
Set newData = wsData.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)                   '<~locate last cell and offset 1 row below

With newData                            '<~defines that we are working with the cell below the last non-blank cell
  .Offset(0, 0).Value = itemName        '<~passes the item name
  .Offset(0, 1).Value = itemPrice       '<~passes the item price
End With

Set newData = Nothing                   '<~post procedure cleaning
Set wsData = Nothing                    '<~post procedure cleaning

wbData.Save                             '<~save
wbData.Close

End Sub
```

This might be a chunky code. But IMO, this is flexible in case you want to change some part/s of the code.